# Logout is offering to log me out of sites I don't even have accounts on (in Chrome)

Tags: bug, logout

The new logout with checkbox thingy is broken.

> [image: chrome]

Thank you for logging me out on stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com, like you are supposed to. And also (very helpfully) logging me out of askubuntu.com, mathoverflow.com, serverfault.com, stackapps.com, and superuser.com as well.

**Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure I don't have accounts on all those sites.** I only have accounts on stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com.

**This is broken on Chrome 45, but works correctly on IE 11.**

This is what it looks like on IE 11:

> [image: IE]

Comment: I saw the same issue yesterday, I do have accounts on all those sites but I wasn't logged in on those for sure, as a matter of fact, I got the same list you got...

Comment: @rene What browser were you on? From what I've seen, it's broken in chrome, but works fine on ie.

Comment: Yep, that was in Chrome/Win7

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like on IE 11?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I've added the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, I see the same thing on Firefox / Linux as you see on Chrome. I'm honestly not sure *how* you're seeing something different on IE, since the list of sites appears to be hardcoded into the HTML sent from the server, but since you posted a screenshot, I do believe you.

Comment: Um, it's broken in Chrome but not in IE? **How could that be?!** But anyhow, I think Chrome is the SE devs' priority here, and this isn't a life-and-death bug, so I think you shouldn't expect this to be fixed any time soon, unless it's really easy to fix.

Comment: @Illyasviel did you have accounts on of those sites in the past and deleted them? Do you have other accounts there, which are not associated with this main account of yours? (no need for names, just yes/no)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I repro-ed this as well and my answer to your question is: NO

Comment: @rene weird, you also see only two domains listed on IE? My answer was going to be "it's just listing all of SE domains", but seeing different list in different browser kind of makes it incorrect.

Comment: Today I see the same list in all browsers I try but that wasn't the case yesterday. So your statement seems premature @ShadowWizard

Comment: @rene OK, let Anna take the lead here, pretty sure she'll pop up sooner or later. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did have an account on Stack Overflow at the time I posted the question, but that was it. (I deleted the account later.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are logged into every domain we control, even if you don't necessarily have profiles on all those sites. I'm guessing your IE11 sessions predate that login behaviour, which is why you see a different list.

I'm not entirely sold on which is better - technical accuracy (you *are* logged into all those domains) or user-friendliness (not showing domains you don't expect to see). The latter may win out, though it's somewhat more difficult to implement, but I want to think about it a bit more. I'm open to arguments for or against either approach.

Comment: User friendly is better in my opinion, most users in the non-SOFU sites don't have technical background and will be quite confused from all of this.

Comment: Though the truth might be that you are technically logged in on all these sites, making it part of the experience with this kind of message is unnecessarily intrusive to some and will seem technically flawed to many.

Comment: So the logout screen was on purpose. Thanks for your response.